# Jquery is not working in Windows phonegap 1.3 version

Tags: jquery, json, cordova, windows-phone

I developed a Windows phone gap application(Phone gap 1.3.0 version) which contains JQuery code also. my code is shown below

```
function loginSend() {
  navigator.notification.alert("inside login send");
  $.getJSON('data/login.json', function (data) {
    navigator.notification.alert("hi data getting");
  });
}
```

Here  `getJSON` method is not working . where as `alert` is working though it is not a jquery method.  can any one resolve my problem.

This is my www folder struture

```
data->login.json
js->Jqueries ' .js
```

So every thing is working except   `$.getJSOn` method

Comment: Your `navigator.notification.alert` is missing a callback function, as specified in the [PhoneGap API reference](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.3.0/phonegap_notification_notification.md.html#notification.alert). Maybe that's causing the problem? Your `$.getJSON` looks fine to me!

Comment: navigator.notification.alert is working ,$.getJSON() isnot working

Answer (score 0):

it didn't work for me too for some reason. I ended up using another library for all ajax operations. check out  http://www.freelancephp.net/simpleajax-small-ajax-javascript-object/